# Open dropdown from javascript

Tags: javascript, android, mobile

I there ANY way in javascript that we could trigger a select element (dropdown list) to open (i.e. drop)?

After searching alot on the web, it seems the answer to this question is no, but I decided to give it a try on here as well.

I know there are some css tricks that you can set the opacity of your select to 0 and place it over other elements to receive click, but that is not useful in my case.

Also there are tons of js APIs that bring the same dropdown functionality to browsers but they are not good solutions for me because then on mobile browsers (where the OS has a totally different mobile-friendly popup for dropdowns) the functionality would be seriously poor.

[Note] I specifically need to do this in an android browser, in case there is a hack for this special case.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by **put it over**? do you have a pictorial representation?

Comment: I'm just explaining that there are some css3 tricks but not useful -> I have to use js to open it.

Comment: Ummm, maybe dynamically set the multiple attribute to turn it into a listbox, then when someone selects and item, remove that attribute?  But this is a bad road to go down.  Adjust your requirements - your users are capable of hitting their own dropdown.

Comment: Do you have to use a true `<select>` element? This could certainly be accomplished with a custom select-like control if you weren't opposed to reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @AdamRackis and FishBasketGordo: see my new comments in the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could assign a value to the `size` attribute. This causes the number of visible options to change. This simulates a "drop-down". Add `position:relative` to a container, and `position:absolute` to the select to prevent the element from pushing other elements away.

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HQwXj/

Comment: this is cool, but again this is a workaround that "simulates dropping"  of a select element. see my comments in question about mobile browsers.

Comment: @valipour Does the `focus` method work? (I don't have an android browser to test it out).

Comment: I don't think that it's possible then. You might want to edit your question's title/tags so that it's more clear that you're looking for a mobile-only suolution.